# ASP.Net MVC 4 Multiple Database

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, ef-code-first

I have a Solution with a MVC 4 Web Application `(code first)` and four Class library as follow `DataLayer, DomainClasses, Model, ServiceLayer`. I'm using `Unit of Work`, `IoC`, `DependencyResolution` approaches in my project.

Now I need to connect another database and get data from it in addition of my current database.

To do so, I added one more `ConnectionString` in `web.config`:

```
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="ConnectionString1" />
   <add name="ConnectionString2" />
</connectionStrings>
```

for my current database I have something like this:

```
namespace Employment.DataLayer.Context
{
    public class EmploymentDbContext : DbContext, IUnitOfWork
    {
        // public DbSet<Register> Registers { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            // modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new RegisterConfig());

            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }

        #region IUnitOfWork Members

        public new IDbSet<TEntity> Set<TEntity>() where TEntity : class
        {
            return base.Set<TEntity>();
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

and if I need to do anything with database I work with service layer like this:

```
namespace Employment.ServiceLayer.EFServices
{
    public class RegisterService : IRegsiter
    {
        private readonly IDbSet<Register> _register;
        private readonly IUnitOfWork _uow;

        public RegisterService(IUnitOfWork uow)
        {
            _uow = uow;
            _register = _uow.Set<Register>();
            // Now I can use _register.add, _register.remove, _register.find, ...
        }
    }
}
```

the second database is already exists and I need to query a table let say `table1`. how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the particular patterns you are using by I have a MVC application that has it's own code first database and accesses other databases. I created a repository in the Data Access Layer that uses ADO.NET:

```
public class GenericRepository : IGenericRepository 
{

    private readonly string _connectionString;
    private readonly string _tableName;
    public GenericRepository(string connectionString, string tableName)
    {
        _connectionString = connectionString;
        _tableName = tableName;
    }

    public DataTable GetGenericLog()
    {
        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
        using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
        {

            StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
            sql.Append("Select * from " + _tableName);

            using (var dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql.ToString(), _connectionString))
            {
                var dataTable = new DataTable();

                dataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);

                return dataTable;

            }
        }
    }
}
```